# explain the grammar of "have had to" in the sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

here is the sentence

"We've had to order a part that's only made overseas and it will take few days to get here"

but why not just "we've ordered a part......"

Does it mean the obligation has already been done?

Answer (score 1):

**Present Perfect tense**:  `Sub + have + V3`

this tense  shows the just completed actions in present.

**eg:**(1):

> **i have gone** to the post office to buy some cards.

**eg:**(2): **conversation:**

> **`John:`** `Why didn't you come to the Movie?`
>
> **`Rosee:`** **`I have had`**`to go to buy a medicine for our neighbors, so i didn't come.`
>
> **Sub + have+ V3** (Here **had** is past participle)
>
> (here John should have gone to the movie if didn't to go for
>   medicine)
>
> **`Have + had to + V1`** also gives the same meaning as **should, must, ought to** in Past period

**Past Perfect tense**:  `Sub + had + V3`

this tense  shows the just completed actions in past period.

**eg:**

> i had gone to the post office to buy some cards.

**Have to:** `have to + V1`

*have to* gives the same meaning like **should, must, ought to** with present and future meaning.

**eg:**(1): **conversation:**

> ```
> John: let us go to the movie?
> Rosee: i have to go to buy a medicine for our neighbors, so i won't come.
> ```
>
> (here John would have gone to the movie if need not to go for
>   medicine)

**eg:(2):**

> i have to go to the post office to buy some cards.

**eg:(3):**

> we have to wear a uniform in our school.